# Android N permission Issue

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I have Android N Developer preview version on my testing device, and I am asking for runtime permission during the app launch.

But unfortunately, the app doesn't display the alert dialog to grant the permissions. I am using the below code:

**Launcher Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if(checkPermissions()) {
            renderView();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {

        int permissionWriteStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE);
        int permissionPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

        Log.i("permission",(permissionWriteStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) + "");
        //This prints false

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionWriteStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE);
        }
        if (permissionPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("permission", "in if");
            //I get this in the logs

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.***.***'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solution (1/2)**

By changing the build tools version to `24.0.1` I am getting the alert for `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission but not for the permission group `STORAGE`.
Do we need to ask separately for each permission of a permission group?

**EDIT 2: Solution (2/2)**

I managed to solve it by replacing `Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE` with `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. As per the docs, you just need confirmation for one dangerous permission for the whole group.

> The user only needs to grant permission once for each permission group. If your app requests any other permissions in that group (that are listed in your app manifest), the system automatically grants them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure but changed build tools version

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.***.***'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
}
```

Comment: Changing the `buildtoolsVersion` to `24.0.1` did help me. Now i get the dialog for the `READ_PHONE_STATE` but not for the permission group `STORAGE`

Comment: @PrerakSola,Try this. Many time not get values (LoginActivity.this, ...)

Comment: I was able to solve it by replacing `Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE` with `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Thank for your help.

Comment: This answer solved half of my problem, the other half solution is mentioned in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

User ActivityCompat insteadof ContextCompat

```
int permissionWriteStorage = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE);
int permissionPhoneState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, because using `ContextCompat` I get the correct value for the permission. I get `false` during the first launch, which is correct.

Comment: Check listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()] is correctly returning String[]. Try for one permission first

Answer (score 0):

I know this technique is messy but why not simply use it?

You can achieve multiple permissions too.

```
void getPermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Final_maps.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    CODE);

    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setLocationEnabled();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement onRequestPermissionsResult method, permission alert won't be shown.

Comment: I have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

give permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

> Then paste your code in in Activity

```
 private void getPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

> Also Call this override method

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        }
    }

}
```